# Why doesn't css work with this div?

Tags: html, css

So I have a body here:

```
 <body>
 <div id=”first”>
    <span class=”red”>This is a DIV Container</span>

    Or
    <br>
    This
</div>
```

And I have a style sheet with this

```
#first{
    background-color:red;
}
```

But the background color doesn't change. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

Here's a jsfiddle with the code

https://jsfiddle.net/fuz5uqfb/

Doesn't worth there either.

Comment: interesting indeed :) you don't close your body tag but I tested it and doesn't work, selector is alright

Comment: @MarkoMackic  Ya, the body tag is just a copy and paste error on my part. Turns out the assignment I have put the wrong kind of brackets (” vs ") on the pdf and brackets (code editor) makes the two of them look really similar and behave the same.

Comment: I know  that :) I was just about to answer :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong kind of quotation marks for your div `id` and span `class`. It should be this:

```
<body>
    <div id="first">
        <span class="red">This is a DIV Container</span>

        Or
        <br>
        This
    </div>
</body>
```

## [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fuz5uqfb/4/)

Comment: Well... Thanks a lot! I copied it from a pdf and didn't check those.

Comment: No problem, in the future you can paste your code into a text editor and remove formatting to make sure you're getting the `plain text`, that way you won't run into any syntax issues!

Comment: That's so weird. I always thought quotation marks were neutral in code. Anyways, if you want just the text to be colored in red and not the entire row it is in, use the property: `display: inline-block;`

Comment: @btrballin The red color was just so I could see if the css applied to the div quickly. But thanks anyways!